# Unable to move alertController to UIViewController extension, if it requires handler function

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Throughout my program, I call UIAlertControllers multiple times.  To make things easier to read, I was able to successfully factor out AlertController if it only has an "OK" action with nil as the handler.

I am struggling to do the same thing if I want to pass a function that I want to link as UIAlertAction.  **func showOKCancelAlertController**  does not compile

```
showOKAlertController(title: "Network Error", message: "Unable to download photos") //This is an example of how I call Alert Controller throughout my code.

extension UIViewController {
    func showOKAlertController(title: String, message: String){
        let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(myAlertController, animated: true)
    }

    func showOKCancelAlertController(title: String, message: String, okFunction: UIAlertAction ){
        let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: okFunction))
        myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(myAlertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the error that you are facing is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIAlertAction' to expected argument type
>   '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

that's because `okFunction` parameter of type `UIAlertAction`, this is the incorrect part. You should let `okFunction` to be of type `((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?` instead:

```
func showOKCancelAlertController(title: String, message: String, okFunction: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?) {
    let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: okFunction))
    myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(myAlertController, animated: true)
}
```

and that's because the `UIAlertAction` init signature is:

`init(title: String?, style: UIAlertAction.Style, handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil)`,

the `handler` parameter expects `((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?`.

Therefore, you call it as:

```
showOKCancelAlertController(title: "title", message: "message") { _ in
    print("here is what to do when tapping the OK button")
}
```

---

Also, in case there is no action for the OK button, what you could is to give a default `nil` value for `okFunction` parameter:

```
func showOKCancelAlertController(title: String, message: String, okFunction: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil)
```

and calling it as:

```
showOKCancelAlertController(title: "title", message: "message")
```

Actually, this leads to a pretty cool thing to your case which is: at this point you don't even need to implement two different methods, you could just implement one method and pass the `okFunction` parameter for it only if it's needed! Example:

```
func showAlertController(title: String, message: String, okFunction: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil) {
    let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: okFunction))
    if let okFun = okFunction {
        myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: okFun))
    }

    present(myAlertController, animated: true)
}
```

If you want to show it with one button:

```
showAlertController(title: "title", message: "message")
```

and for two buttons:

```
showAlertController(title: "title", message: "message") { _ in
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The handler expected type is `((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)?` not `UIAlertAction`

Update your code to

```
func showOKCancelAlertController(title: String, message: String, okFunction: ((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)? ){
     let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
     myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: okFunction))
     myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
     present(myAlertController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be

```
extension UIViewController { 
    func showOKAlertController(title: String, message: String,ok:@escaping(() -> ())) {
        let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: { (al) in
            ok()
        }))
        myAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(myAlertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

---

```
showOKAlertController(title: "This is title", message: "this is message") {
   print("ok")
}
```

Comment: It could be also a good idea, however I'd suggest to make it optional in case tapping the OK button should not do anything...

Answer (score 1):

Improve your code to my way

This is flexible to deal the completion handler

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showOKAlertController(title: String, message: String? = nil, okCompletion: @escaping (() -> ()) = {}, presentCompletion: @escaping (() -> ()) = {}) {
        let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in
            okCompletion()
        }
        myAlertController.addAction(okAction)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
                presentCompletion()
            }
        }
    }

    func showOKCancelAlertController(title: String, message: String? = nil, okCompletion: @escaping (() -> ()) = {}, cancelCompletion: @escaping (() -> ()) = {}, presentCompletion: @escaping (() -> ()) = {}) {
        let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in
            okCompletion()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (cancel: UIAlertAction) in
            cancelCompletion()
        }
        myAlertController.addAction(okAction)
        myAlertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
                presentCompletion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
showOKAlertController(title: "message")
```

or

```
showOKAlertController(title: "message", message: "message")
```

or

```
showOKCancelAlertController(title: "message", message: nil, okCompletion: {
    // ok completion handling
}) {
    // present completion handling
}
```

or you can refer above useful from my [gist](https://gist.github.com/joshua24322/2b48a026452e1184fce85ef68f18014e)